# Minimize a function containing a file exportation

Tags: mathematical-optimization, files-and-directories

I have the following problem:

```
gigi[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] := With[{go = 2},
  a + b^2 + b + d^2 + e + f^2;
  dfe = 2;
  dd = Log[a] + dfe + go;
  Export["pd.dat", dd];
  alt = Import["pd.dat"]
  ]
```

Its only an example, as my real code is too complicate to post here. I am obliged to export and read a file (since one of my functions in a package has to read files and I can't modify it). 
If one runs this function with some input arguments it work good. Problems begin when I want to minimize this function.

```
Minimize[{gigi[a, b, c, d, e, f]}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, 
 StepMonitor :> Print["Step to x = ", a]]
```

The export of the files messes up with FindMinimum. What can I do??

Comment: Is `StepMonitor` a valid option for `Minimize`?

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you are exporting the definition of `dd` into the file `pd.dat`, but it isn't getting imported back correctly. In other words, `alt` ≠ `dd`. If you want them to be identical, you could try: `alt =ToExpression[Import["pd.dat", "String"]]`

Comment: This was what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments above, the problem is that `Import["pd.dat"]` does not correctly interpret the exported text file. You can see this by evaluating `gigi[a, b, c, d, e, f]` which returns `{{4, "+", "Log[a]"}}`. Since the file "pd.dat" contains only "4 + Log[a]", this gets interpreted as the number 4, followed by a "+" sign, followed by the string "Log[a]".

To fix this, you can use the `Get[]` function that reads in and evaluates each expression. For example, you could change the import line to read: `alt = Get["pd.dat"]`. (This is effectively identical to my comment suggestion to use `alt=ToExpression[Import["pd.dat", "String"]]`)

If your goal is to export and import full definitions though, you may also consider using the `Save[]` function together with `Get[]`. `Save` creates a text file that includes the variable name. For example, `Save["pd2.dat", dd]` creates a file that reads "dd = 4 + Log[a]". Then if you `Get["pd2.dat"]` this will set `dd` equal to `4+Log[a]`.

Using `Save[]` and `Get[]` together is easier, but can also overwrite definitions. Here is an illustrative example where `dd` is saved, clear, then imported during `Get`:

```
gigi2[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] := 
 With[{go = 2}, a + b^2 + b + d^2 + e + f^2;
  dfe = 2;
  dd = Log[a] + dfe + go;
  Save["pd2.dat", dd];
  Clear[dd];
  alt=Get["pd2.dat"]]

gigi2[a, b, c, d, e, f]
 (* 4 + Log[a] *)

dd
 (* 4 + Log[a] *)
```